Конвертация описания таблиц базы данных из docx в dbml
Пытаюсь пока вкатится в анализ данных.
Стоит весьма необычная задача.
Есть описание набора таблиц базы данных в docx (пример ниже на скриншоте.
Мне для анализа данных и перестройки всего и вся необходимо перевести в синтакс dbml.
Подскажите пожалуйста пару способов конвертации. Пока что думаю что это будет скрипт на питоне, но не совсем понимаю как мне правильно читать и распознавать данный docx.

Пока что ничего конкретного

Смотря сколько там таблиц. Если там 10 таблиц примерно такого формата, то вообще нет смысла заморачиваться, проще руками все описать.

А так - берете тот же python-docx, который вы сами же в метках указали, и парсите.
